# Problemas con Google Cloud

Tags: python, python-3.7, google-cloud-platform

Estoy tratando de usar google cloud pero cuando ejecuta `dev_appserver.py` con un ambiente virtual para python 3.7.X tiene un error. Instala todo bien pero cuando va a generar el localhost pone el error:

> assert sys.version_info[0] == 2 AssertionError de: dev_appserver.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a que `dev_appserver` por ahora requieren Python 2.x. A pesar del end of life de Python 2 y que se lleva muchos años avisando, aún quedan proyectos dependientes de Python 2 y me temo que quedarán algunos un tiempo más, portar proyectos grandes no es simple y siempre no se tiene o se quieren asignar recursos para ello.

Extraído y traducido de la de la [documentación oficial](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs#install_the_latest_cloud_sdk_version):

> Nota: El SDK de Cloud usa Python 2 de forma predeterminada, pero
>   pronto se cambiará a Python 3 (ejecuta gcloud topic startup a fin de
>   obtener información sobre las exclusiones y la configuración del
>   intérprete de Python para usar una versión diferente). Considera
>   actualizar a Python 3 para evitar interrupciones en el futuro.

Pero si nos vamos a [gcloud topic startup](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/startup):

> Actualmente gcloud requiere Python versión 2.7.x o 3.5 y superior.
>
> Otras herramientas Python incluidas en el SDK de Cloud por ahora no soportan Python 3, incluyendo:
>
> - dev_appserver
> - endpointscfg

Me temo que por ahora, esperemos que porten pronto lo que les queda a Python 3, no te queda más que instalar Python 2.7.x para poder usar `dev_appserver`.